# Animate contentInset

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

I'd like to animate the contentInset of a scrollView which belongs to a UIWebView. I tried the following code, but unfortunately the inset just jumps when it runs

```
UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState;
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 delay:0 options:options animations:^
 {
     self.webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100 ,120,120,120);
 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Does anyone know how i can make a smooth animation of contentInset?
I also tried the option AllowAnimatedContent with no luck

Comment: Are you attempting this animation at the same time as the scroll view is in motion (dragging or decelerating)?

Comment: no, only keyboard will show at same time (that is why I used inset, so the rest of the page can still be "seen" through the keyboard)

Comment: I think your first approach should be to replace the UIWebView with a plain UIScrollView of equivalent content size, and see if your approach works on that. If so, there's probably something in UIWebView that's repositioning while overriding animation, and unfortunately there's not much you can do about that.

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
CGFloat height = 80.0f //change to whichever value you want

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    [self.peopleCollectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(height, 0, 0, 0)];
}];
[self.peopleCollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -height) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5.1

```
UIView.animate({
     self.tableView.contentInset = .init(top: tableViewOffset, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
     self.tableView.setContentOffset(.init(x: 0, y: -tableViewOffset), animated: false)
  }, onComplete: { Swift.print("Anim completed") })
```

Comment: By adding the setContentOffset in the anime closure you also match the animation speed. Unlike accepted answer.